# Concurrency, Parallelism & Multiprocessing for a time sensitive application

Tags: python, concurrency, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

need some guidance on program design.  I'm a beginner, so I don't know if there's a better way to approach the problem.  I've tried to use multiprocessing as well as asyncio to resolve a timing issue. Under multiprocessing, which I thought was the best approach, my program runs a sql query in one function in one process, and that function passes the result to a second function via Manager().list([]) running in another process.

I'm using the schedule module to run the sql query function every 10 seconds, and there is a second function that runs every second. (I need to evaluate the date/time returned from the sql query for a subsequent action based on current date/time in the second function.)  What I'm seeing is that the sql function seems to interrupt the second time evaluation function, e.g. I'll see the current date/time increment in seconds as expected in the time evaluation function, but when the sql query function runs, I see a gap of one, two or three seconds (and a matching date/time from the sql query to the current date/time doesn't fire the desire action) and then the date/time with start to increment again.

I'm not sure if multiprocessing is working as intended, or if I have an error in my code, or if I should try another approach (wide open to suggestions)

Thanks!!!!

Was really hoping to avoid posting my code, I'm a real beginner with python, and I know this is a mess (incredible understatement!) and I'm more than a little embarrassed by it...

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import pendulum
import schedule
import time
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import paho.mqtt.client as mqttc
import json

def worker(data, final_list):
    def create_connection(host_name, data_base, user_name, user_password):
        print('create_connection:111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111')
        connection = None
        try:
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(
                host=host_name,
                database=data_base,
                user=user_name,
                passwd=user_password,
                # Auto commit
                autocommit=True
            )
            print("Connection to MySQL DB from function successful")
        except Error as e:
            print(f"The error '{e}' occurred")
        return connection

    def query_database():
        print('running query_database:22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222')
        connection = create_connection("10.0.0.XXX", "webcalendar", "python2", "XXXXXXX")
        queryappointments = """

            SELECT DISTINCT
              webcal_entry.cal_id,
              webcal_entry.cal_date, 
              webcal_entry.cal_due_time,
              webcal_entry.cal_name,
              webcal_entry.cal_description,
              webcal_entry_user.cal_status,
              webcal_entry.cal_time
            FROM
              webcal_entry_user
              LEFT JOIN webcal_entry ON webcal_entry.cal_id = webcal_entry_user.cal_id
            WHERE 
             webcal_entry_user.cal_status = 'A'
            """

        cursor = connection.cursor()
        unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_tuples = None
        try:
            cursor.execute(queryappointments)
            unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_tuples = cursor.fetchall()
        except Error as e:
            print(f"The error '{e}' occurred")
        finally:
            if (connection.is_connected()):
                cursor.close()
                connection.close()
                print("MySQL connection is closed")
        return unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_tuples

    def convert_unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_tuples_to_list_of_lists():
        unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_tuples = query_database()
        print('running convert_unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_tuples_to_list_of_lists:333333333333333333333')
        unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists = [list(appointments) for appointments in
                                                     unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_tuples]
        print(unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists)
        return unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists

    def create_untimed_reminders_in_list_of_lists():
        # Webcalendar uses a -1 in webcal_entry.cal_time to indicate an untimed appointment
        # this function creates a list of lists for these entries
        print('running create_untimed_reminders_in_list_of_lists:444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444')
        untimed_reminders = []
        unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists = convert_unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_tuples_to_list_of_lists()
        for i in (range(len(unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists))):
            if unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists[i][6] == -1:
                untimed_reminders.append(unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists[i])
        print("untimed_reminders:")
        print(untimed_reminders)
        return untimed_reminders

    def remove_untimed_appointments_in_list_of_lists():
        # Webcalendar uses a -1 in webcal_entry.cal_time to indicate an untimed appointment
        # this function removes those entries
        print('running remove_untimed_appointments_in_list_of_lists:555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555')
        unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists = convert_unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_tuples_to_list_of_lists()
        for i in reversed(range(len(unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists))):
            if unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists[i][6] == -1:
                del unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists[i]
        print("remindersminus:")
        print(unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists)
        return unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists

    def format_appointments_in_list_of_lists_with_date_time():
        unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists = remove_untimed_appointments_in_list_of_lists()
        print('running format_appointments_in_list_of_lists_with_date_time:6666666666666666666666666666666666666666')
        # Clear final_list = Manager().list([]) so we don't keep reappending same appointments
        final_list[:] = []
        final_list[:]

        for sub_list in unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists:
            # Webcalendar stores the appointment date as an integer in webcal_entry.cal_date and the appointment
            # time as an integer in webcal_entry.cal_due_time, we need to combine these two fields and add a "T"
            # between them to create an ISO 8601 Datetime string
            sub_list[0] = (str(sub_list[1])) + "T" + str('{:>06d}'.format(sub_list[2]))
            sub_list.remove(sub_list[1])
            sub_list.remove(sub_list[1])

        for sub_list in unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists:
            # Webcalendar stores datetimes as UTC, we need to convert the string we created to an UTC datetime objects
            sub_list[0] = (pendulum.parse(sub_list[0], tz='UTC'))

        for sub_list in unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists:
            # Since we want the MQTT messages to fire at the local date/time, we need to convert the datetime objects to
            # the local timezone
            sub_list[0] = sub_list[0].in_tz('America/Los_Angeles')
        for item in unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists:
            final_list.append(item)
        print('unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists:')
        print(unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists)
        print('final_list from worker:')
        print(final_list)

    format_appointments_in_list_of_lists_with_date_time()

def worker2(data, final_list):
    def evaluate_appointment_time_in_formatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists_to_current_time_and_publish_to_MQTT_if_equal():
        client = mqttc.Client("SuperPython")
        client.connect("10.0.0.XXX", 1883)
        currentdatetime = pendulum.now().replace(microsecond=0)
        # Since Pendulum is scheduled to run the job function every .6 seconds, we need to trim off the microseconds from
        # the datetime object or it will miss entries because Webcalendar entries have only whole minutes
        print(
            'running evaluate_appointment_time_in_formatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists_to_current_time_and_publish_to_MQTT_if_equal:88888')
        print('final_list from MQTT publish:')
        print(final_list)
        for i in final_list:
            print('entry:')
            print(i[2])
            print('i[0]:')
            print(i[0].to_datetime_string())
            print('currentdatetime:')
            print(currentdatetime.to_datetime_string())
            if i[0] == currentdatetime:
                payload = {"text": i[2], "siteId": "default", "lang": "", "id": "", "sessionId": "", "volume": 1.0}
                #            print(json.dumps(payload))
                mqttc.publish(topic="hermes/tts/say", payload=json.dumps(payload))
        client.disconnect()

    evaluate_appointment_time_in_formatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists_to_current_time_and_publish_to_MQTT_if_equal()


def run_schedule():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
#        time.sleep(1)

def run_worker2(input_list_one, final_list):
    schedule.every(0.01).minutes.do(worker2, input_list_one, final_list)
    run_schedule()

def run_worker(input_list_two, final_list):
    schedule.every(0.50).minutes.do(worker, input_list_two, final_list)
    run_schedule()


def run_job():
    p = Process(target=run_worker2, args=(input_list_one, final_list))
    c = Process(target=run_worker, args=(input_list_two, final_list))
    p.start()
    c.start()
    p.join()
#    c.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Manager() as manager:
        lock = manager.Lock()
        final_list = Manager().list([])
        input_list_one = []
        input_list_two = []
    run_job()
```

Here's the relevant part of the output, notice that in this example there is a one second gap in the currentdatetime print statement (2021-04-06 11:51:46 -> 2021-04-06 11:51:48) in the worker2 function, which means the worker2 function sometimes misses appointments that fall into that specific time segment. I've verified this multiple times by rerunning the program; sometime everything works because the worker function doesn't interrupt the worker2 evaluation when the time evaluation is true for the appointment/s, other times, appointments get missed when the worker function is running during that exact time and sometimes there is is even a larger gap, depending on how long worker function takes to run.

```
currentdatetime:
2021-04-06 11:51:46
running remove_untimed_appointments_in_list_of_lists:555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555
running query_database:22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
create_connection:111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
Connection to MySQL DB from function successful
MySQL connection is closed
running convert_unformatted_appointments_in_list_of_tuples_to_list_of_lists:333333333333333333333
[[2, 20200331, 70000, '202003310:00', '<p>March 31st at 12 am</p>', 'A', 70000], [3, 20200331, 110000, 'hermes/tts/say', 'March 31st at 4 AM', 'A', 110000], [4, 20200331, 150000, '2020033108:00', '<p>March 31st at 8 am</p>', 'A', 150000], [5, 20200331, 190000, '2020033112:00', '<p>March 31st at 12PM noon</p>', 'A', 190000], [6, 20200331, 230000, '2020033116:00', '<p>March 31st at 4pm</p>', 'A', 230000], [7, 20200401, 10000, '2020033118:00', '<p>March 31st at 6pm</p>', 'A', 10000], [8, 20200401, 30000, '2020033120:00', '<p>March 31 at 8 pm</p>', 'A', 30000], [9, 20200331, 0, '20200331', '<p>March 31st Untimed event</p>', 'A', -1], [10, 20200331, 151000, '2020033108:10', '<p>March 31st 8:10am</p>', 'A', 151000], [11, 20200401, 0, '2020033117:00', 'March 31st at 5:00 pm???', 'A', 0], [13, 20200401, 1000, '2020033117:10', '<p>March 31st at 5:10pm</p>', 'A', 1000], [14, 20200407, 200000, '2020040713:00', '<p>April 7th at 1:00 pm</p>', 'A', 200000], [15, 20210222, 10000, 'json', 'json', 'A', 10000], [17, 20210226, 195000, 'test at 11:50 #1', 'test at 11:50 #1', 'A', 195000], [18, 20210302, 200000, 'test at noon', 'test at noon', 'A', 200000], [19, 20210404, 202900, 'Woo Hoo It really works four!', 'Woo Hoo It really works four!', 'A', 202900], [20, 20210305, 0, 'Untimed Event 3/5', 'Untimed Event 3/5', 'A', -1]]
remindersminus:
[[2, 20200331, 70000, '202003310:00', '<p>March 31st at 12 am</p>', 'A', 70000], [3, 20200331, 110000, 'hermes/tts/say', 'March 31st at 4 AM', 'A', 110000], [4, 20200331, 150000, '2020033108:00', '<p>March 31st at 8 am</p>', 'A', 150000], [5, 20200331, 190000, '2020033112:00', '<p>March 31st at 12PM noon</p>', 'A', 190000], [6, 20200331, 230000, '2020033116:00', '<p>March 31st at 4pm</p>', 'A', 230000], [7, 20200401, 10000, '2020033118:00', '<p>March 31st at 6pm</p>', 'A', 10000], [8, 20200401, 30000, '2020033120:00', '<p>March 31 at 8 pm</p>', 'A', 30000], [10, 20200331, 151000, '2020033108:10', '<p>March 31st 8:10am</p>', 'A', 151000], [11, 20200401, 0, '2020033117:00', 'March 31st at 5:00 pm???', 'A', 0], [13, 20200401, 1000, '2020033117:10', '<p>March 31st at 5:10pm</p>', 'A', 1000], [14, 20200407, 200000, '2020040713:00', '<p>April 7th at 1:00 pm</p>', 'A', 200000], [15, 20210222, 10000, 'json', 'json', 'A', 10000], [17, 20210226, 195000, 'test at 11:50 #1', 'test at 11:50 #1', 'A', 195000], [18, 20210302, 200000, 'test at noon', 'test at noon', 'A', 200000], [19, 20210404, 202900, 'Woo Hoo It really works four!', 'Woo Hoo It really works four!', 'A', 202900]]
running format_appointments_in_list_of_lists_with_date_time:6666666666666666666666666666666666666666
running evaluate_appointment_time_in_formatted_appointments_in_list_of_lists_to_current_time_and_publish_to_MQTT_if_equal:88888
final_list from MQTT publish:
[[DateTime(2020, 3, 31, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('America/Los_Angeles')), '202003310:00', '<p>March 31st at 12 am</p>', 'A', 70000], [DateTime(2020, 3, 31, 4, 0, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('America/Los_Angeles')), 'hermes/tts/say', 'March 31st at 4 AM', 'A', 110000], [DateTime(2020, 3, 31, 8, 0, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('America/Los_Angeles')), '2020033108:00', '<p>March 31st at 8 am</p>', 'A', 150000], [DateTime(2020, 3, 31, 12, 0, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('America/Los_Angeles')), '2020033112:00', '<p>March 31st at 12PM noon</p>', 'A', 190000], [DateTime(2020, 3, 31, 16, 0, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('America/Los_Angeles')), '2020033116:00', '<p>March 31st at 4pm</p>', 'A', 230000], [DateTime(2020, 3, 31, 18, 0, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('America/Los_Angeles')), '2020033118:00', '<p>March 31st at 6pm</p>', 'A', 10000], [DateTime(2020, 3, 31, 20, 0, 0, tzinfo=Timezone('America/Los_Angeles')), '2020033120:00', '<p>March 31 at 8 pm</p>', 'A', 30000]]
entry:
<p>March 31st at 12 am</p>
i[0]:
2020-03-31 00:00:00
currentdatetime:
2021-04-06 11:51:48
```

Again, I know this code is a nightmare, but I'll keep improving it as my knowledge grows. (I hope!!)

Comment: Your problem *description* is quite vague. Instead, provide [mcve].

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing the code.